# Load PDF document with PDF-LIB on Node gives TypeError

Tags: javascript, typescript, pdf

For a project I need to edit pdf files. For this usecase I'm using PDF Lib and got some good results.
Currently I only have problems when loading an existing PDF, as you can see in the error message:

> TypeError: `pdf` must be of type `string` or `Uint8Array` or `ArrayBuffer`, but was actually of type `undefined`

And here is the code which causes this error:

```
const pdfData = await fs.readFile('./test.pdf', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
});
const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(pdfData);
```

Anyone who also ran into this error?

Comment: Looks like you're not using the Promise-based implementation of `fs`

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that `fs.readFile` is an asynchronous API that doesn't return a value.  Instead of importing / requiring `fs`, instead import `fs/promises`:

```js
import promiseBasedFs from 'node:fs/promises';
// Instead of
// import fs as oldStyleFs from 'node:fs';
```

In the new `/promises` version of the API `fs.readFile` returns a promise (and doesn't take a callback):

```js
const pdfData = await promiseBasedFs.readFile(yourFilePath, 'utf-8');
const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(pdfData);
```

Alternative, if you can't use the `/promises` version for some reason you can "lift" the call into a Promise either by using `util.promisify`:

```js
const promisifiedReadFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);
const pdfData = await promisifiedReadFile(yourFilePath, 'utf-8');
```

or by wrapping the call to `readFile` explicitly in a `Promise` constructor:

```js
const pdfData = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  oldStyleFs.readFile(yourFilePath, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) reject(err);
    else resolve(data);
  });
});
```

or *even* by switching to callbacks completely and moving your `PDFDocument.load` call inside the callback (not recommended):

```js
fs.readFile(yourFilePath, 'utf-8', async (err, pdfData) => {
  if (err) { /* handle error */ }
  const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(pdfData);
});
```